# HTML 5 Video Request timed out Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timeout, html5-video

When safari's loading a `<video>` and it fails (due to poor internet connection or what have you)

it throws this error to the console

```
Failed to load resource: Request timed out
```

There must be some sort of event handler on HTML5 video tag that we can catch

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_error.asp)
You can do this

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onerror = function() {
    alert("Error! Something went wrong");
// do something else

};
```

Comment: Might I add that you must add the event listener on wherever you have the `src` attribute. So if you have `<video><source src='myvideo'></source></video>` put the error event listener on the source tag instead of the video tag